BTRFS volume unreadable after attempting to btrfs device add -f a USB
Recently, my BTRFS volume (/dev/sdc2) had began to report that it was "too full" to do anything, so I went into my installation USB to try to btrfs balance it. However, balancing was impossible due to the aforementioned device too full error. I read online that this could be mitigated by btrfs device adding a USB to the volume. My USB was previously formatted as FAT32 (/dev/sdd1) and iso (/dev/sdd2), but saw that btrfs device add -f could mitigate this and added the FAT32 partition (/dev/sdd1). However, this was not enough space, so I also did the same thing to the other partition on the USB, which was formatted in some iso format for another Linux distro (/dev/sdd2). This was enough space to rebalance my main volume, however, it returned with block errors and locked itself down into read-only mode. Furthermore, it became unmountable again, returning BTRFS error (device sdc2): devid 2 uuid (long uuid string) is missing followed by chunk tree failures. Running fdisk -l showed that the USB I was using had lost both its partitions. Regardless, I attempted to mount it to see if it had anything on it, however it returned an identical error to the BTRFS volume (sdc2) I was trying to balance.
I've tried every btrfs rescue command on the main BTRFS volume (/dev/sdc2) aside from --repair, and I'm wondering if there's anything I could do to get my volume mountable again as I think that it's solely because of the USB drive being formatted weirdly and becoming unreadable.

USB seems to be died.
